# SQL adding columns based on other columns (sorted)

Tags: sql

I am trying to add on columns to my database.

I have 5 columns of integer data. The values can come in any order.

I want to sort the data by each row, not the column.

So if my data is:

```
Val1 | Val2 | val3 | val4 | val5

  23     15    3      45     2
```

I’d like 5 columns added:

```
Val1’ | Val2’ | val3’ | val4’ | val5’

  2       3      15      23       45
```

My internet searches yield ordering by the aggregate column, not row wise insertion. I could add a calculated column as a min of the 5 columns...how do I do the other 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the table structure and the SQL query that u tried

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.  Also indicate if the rows have a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the data and then reaggregate.  In generic SQL, this looks like:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as val1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as val2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as val3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end) as val4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then val end) as val5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
      from (select id, val1 as val from t union all
            select id, val2 as val from t union all
            select id, val3 as val from t union all
            select id, val4 as val from t union all
            select id, val5 as val from t 
           ) t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Here `id` is the primary key used to define each row.

Two important points.  First, there might be simpler or more efficient methods to do this in some databases.

Second, this suggests a problem with the data model.  The five columns should probably be separate rows in a different table.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Gordon.  Maybe some context helps...think of this as a gradebook, and each student has an ID number.  The grades come into the gradebook sequentially based on assignments (Val1, then Val2, then Val3, and so on).  Each column is a grade for an assignment.  I simply have a desire to sort each row, so that I know the min to max of the grades for that student.  Each student's grades will be different order...thus I thought adding in columns would be the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: @G-Force . . . As I say in the answer, you have the wrong data model.  The assignment grades for each student should be in different *rows* not *columns*.  In any case, this should still work for your problem.

Comment: In your suggested answer, it's finding the max position within the 5 columns, which I understand as well, how to get.  But then I want the 2nd max of the remaining 4, and this becomes the complication....all the way down to the 5th max.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I will have to think about the data model more, the question posted here is a representative sample of a subset of the table, and I was trying to make the question easy to answer, and to learn the query better.  As for your solution, what does "seqnum" come from in the example?  I am trying to understand the logic of the query to help me learn why it works. :)

Comment: @G-Force . .  `seqnum` is assigned via `row_number()`.

Comment: and it works, by the way,.....I just don't understand why. :)

Comment: thanks!!!! I will read more about that, thanks again!

Comment: this will only provide a sorted query....I would need that as the basis for doing new queries....which is why I thought having them permanently sorted in the table would be more efficient.  Is there a way to extend this, to add columns of sorted values, or just change the data in the existing columns to this sorted value, so that I don't have to do this select query each time before doing another operation?

Comment: ideally, based on my current thinking, I think a generated column that incorporates this search (at insertion time, obviously) would be best.  thanks in advance for your expertise!

Comment: @G-Force . . . This answers the question that you asked here.

Comment: fair enough, I'll create another one.  Thanks for all your great advice.  I've marked it, but it doesn't record my result publicly since I'm new here.

Comment: @G-Force . . . As the OP you can accept exactly one answer to each question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm good at interpreting it.

I understood that there are 10 columns, 5 columns you want, and you want to put the remaining 5 as sorted values.

in this case, it is difficult to use one query.

so, i recommend stored procedure.